# Can not serve static content files

Tags: python, google-app-engine

For some reason I can not serve static content files. I have the following structure

```
root
    static
        css
            test.css
app.yaml
```

in app.yaml i have the following handler

```
handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css
```

Now using the navigation bar of the browser (localhost:8080/css/test.css) I'm receiving in the network log error 404 (file not found)

Comment: Are there 2 spaces before `static_dir`?  Are you getting any other errors?

Comment: Yep, there are 2 spaces before static_dir. When I try to reference the test.css trough application the error code is 500 (internal server error).

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: this is a partial trace of the application running in debug mode: INFO     2014-06-20 17:57:28,733 module.py:639] default: "GET /css/test.css HTTP/1.1" 200 42
ERROR    2014-06-20 17:57:28,733 module.py:714] Request to '/css/test.css' failed
TypeError: WSGI response header value u'text/css' is not of type str.

Comment: I found the resolution , sadly I don't know why it happened. So if anyone can explain I would gladly listen and remember. The resolution is to add (mime_type: "text/css") in the handler for static files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't your fault -- it's a bug in App Engine: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11001

There's a thread with some workarounds here: [Google App Engine: Won't serve static assets with below error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106776/google-app-engine-wont-serve-static-assets-with-below-error)