# ERROR appcfg.py:2488 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

I want to deploy changes to my web application on appengine then I got this error, I never change the app.yaml here

```
handlers:

- url: /assets/lib/parsley/(.*\.md)
  static_files: assets/lib/parsley/\1
  upload: assets/lib/parsley/(.*\.md)
  mime_type: text/x-markdown

- url: /assets/lib/nvd3/(.*\.md)
  static_files: assets/lib/nvd3/\1
  upload: assets/lib/nvd3/(.*\.md)
  mime_type: text/x-markdown

- url: /assets/js/(.*\.json)
  static_files: assets/js/\1
  upload: assets/js/(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json

- url: /assets/lib/examples/(.*\.json)
  static_files: assets/lib/examples/\1
  upload: assets/lib/examples/(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json

- url: /assets/css/fonts/glyphicons/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  static_files: assets/css/fonts/glyphicons/\1
  upload: assets/css/fonts/glyphicons/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  mime_type: application/x-woff

- url: /assets/css/fonts/font-awesome/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff|otf))
  static_files: assets/css/fonts/font-awesome/\1
  upload: assets/css/fonts/font-awesome/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff|otf))
  mime_type: application/font-woff 

- url: /assets/css/fontello/font/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  static_files: assets/css/fontello/font/\1
  upload: assets/css/fontello/font/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  mime_type: application/x-woff

- url: /assets/css/font/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  static_files: assets/css/font/\1
  upload: assets/css/font/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  mime_type: application/x-woff

- url: /assets/css
  static_dir: assets/css

- url: /assets/js
  static_dir: assets/js

- url: /assets/lib
  static_dir: assets/lib

- url: /assets/img
  static_dir: assets/img

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
  secure: always
```

and that lead me to this error

```
2014-07-01 19:32:28,868 ERROR appcfg.py:2488 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2329, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2455, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.UploadFile(missing_file, file_handle)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2002, in UploadFile
    file_classification.StaticMimeType())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1442, in AddToBatch
    self.SendSingleFile(path, payload, mime_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1388, in SendSingleFile
    path=path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1684, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 408, in Send
    HttpRequestToString(req, include_data=self.debug_data))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 102, in HttpRequestToString
    'data': req.get_data(),
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 307343: ordinal not in range(128)
07:32 PM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 126, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5220, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5211, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2886, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4890, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3682, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3735, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3618, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2329, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2455, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.UploadFile(missing_file, file_handle)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2002, in UploadFile
    file_classification.StaticMimeType())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1442, in AddToBatch
    self.SendSingleFile(path, payload, mime_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1388, in SendSingleFile
    path=path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1684, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 408, in Send
    HttpRequestToString(req, include_data=self.debug_data))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 102, in HttpRequestToString
    'data': req.get_data(),
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 307343: ordinal not in range(128)
2014-07-01 19:32:30 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

I really don't have idea what happening. It used to be working fine yesterday.

Could someone help me what I am missing here

thanks in advance, Have a great day.

Comment: It might not have anything to do with your app.yaml. It looks like you have a unicode character in a source file somewhere and Python is not happy about that. This answer might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1

Comment: I see, I'll trace it and update it once I knew the answer

Comment: could I trace what file is it? or what line? I'm pretty lost

Comment: Maybe one of your files in the assets directory has a non-ascii file name?

Comment: @Mars i have seen every filename but it is all good i wonder what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the answer here

[Google App Engine: Won't serve static assets with below error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106776/google-app-engine-wont-serve-static-assets-with-below-error)

basically I had an changes in my css so when I upload it that error occurred I never been working in app engine before using php so spare me with this error but this is quick fix

edit the app.yaml every `url : /dir` must have a mime_type for example

`- url: /assets/css<br>
  static_dir: assets/css<br>
  mime_type: "text/css"` 

the problem was solve by this line `mime_type: "text/css"`