# Google App Engine add image to page with static folder

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

i have a problem to use image with static folder path in my page.
this is my app.yaml

```
application: something
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

I have templates, static/images, controllers (has MainHandler.py) folders and in my root i have main.py and app.yaml files. in my templeate folder i have index.html file that contain:

```
<div>
    <img src="images/fig1.jpg">
</div>
```

my problem is when page was loaded i cant see my fig1.jpg picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the url of this page?  If it looks like a subdirectory, then your using a relative path for your image is not pointing to the `images` path.  Try changing to:

```
<div>
    <img src="/images/fig1.jpg">
</div>
```

If using Windows, there is a known bug.  See:

[Google App Engine: Won't serve static assets with below error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106776/google-app-engine-wont-serve-static-assets-with-below-error/24107830#24107830)

Try adding `mime_type: "image/jpeg"` to your image handler, to see if that is the cause.

Comment: thanks a lot @GAEfan , but its not work neither. i am working on my local machine.