# Static image folder with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

There are already a lot of post dealing with this issue but I wasn't able to find a solution to my problem. I am using the Google App Engine Launcher to create a small web application using python. I need to display a picture (`/images/chartname.png`) on my page. I am using the following line of html code `<img width=150 src="/images/chartname.png">` but the picture does not show up. Additionally when I open `http://localhost:8080/images` I get an error 404.

Here's the content of my `.yaml` file:

```
application: app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: app.my_app

- url: /images
  static_dir: images
```

I don't understand why the picture doesn't show up and why `http://localhost:8080/images` returns an error 404.

I've tried the suggestion in this post: [Google App Engine add image to page with static folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799011/google-app-engine-add-image-to-page-with-static-folder) but it didn't do it for me.

Comment: What happens if you swap the 2 url directives in your app.yaml file?

Comment: This is it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reordering the handlers:

```
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: app.my_app
```

Patterns are evaluated in the order they appear in the app.yaml file, from top to bottom. The first mapping whose pattern matches the URL is the one used to handle the request.

Comment: @JeremyL. accept the answer if you think is correct.