# App Engine GO SDK Load CSS file with 500 error

Tags: html, css, google-app-engine

I create a test app locally using App Engine GO.
I have bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js at the same folder and the two files have exactly same content. The file path and handlers as following.

css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css

css/bootstrap/bootstrap.js

> handlers:
>
> - url: /css
>
> static_dir: css

Loading bootstrap.js (localhost:8080/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.js) works fine. But bootstrap.css (localhost:8080/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css) can not be loaded at all, has 500 Internal Server Error. The server log as following.

> c:\Apps\Google\appProjects\myapp>goapp serve
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:57:00,200 devappserver2.py:765] Skipping SDK update check
>   .
>
> WARNING  2014-07-19 08:57:00,211 api_server.py:374] Could not initialize images
>   API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:57:00,230 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http
>   ://localhost:49980
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:57:00,236 dispatcher.py:182] Starting module "default" ru
>   nning at: http ://localhost:8080
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:57:00,242 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at:
>   http ://localhost:8000
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:58:26,872 module.py:627] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13
>   50
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:58:26,914 module.py:627] default: "GET /css/bootstrap/boo
>   tstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:58:27,943 module.py:627] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/
>   1.1" 200 1354
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:58:37,127 module.py:627] default: "GET /css/bootstrap/boo
>   tstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:58:38,219 module.py:627] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/
>   1.1" 200 1354
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:59:38,157 module.py:627] default: "GET /css/bootstrap/boo
>   tstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 145168
>
> ERROR    2014-07-19 08:59:38,157 module.py:675] Request to '/css/bootstrap/boots
>   trap.css' failed
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Apps\Google\go_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.
>   py", line 671, in _handle_request
>
> ```
> return handler.handle(match, environ, wrapped_start_response)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Apps\Google\go_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\static_
>   files_handler.py", line 326, in handle
>
> ```
> return self._handle_path(full_path, environ, start_response)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Apps\Google\go_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\static_
>   files_handler.py", line 181, in _handle_path
>
> ```
> start_response('200 OK', headers)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Apps\Google\go_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.
>   py", line 628, in wrapped_start_response
>
> ```
> return start_response(status, response_headers, exc_info)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Apps\Google\go_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2
>   .py", line 2155, in start_response
>
> ```
> raise TypeError("WSGI response header value %r is not of type str." % v)
> ```
>
> TypeError: WSGI response header value u'text/css' is not of type str.
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:59:38,161 module.py:627] default: "GET /css/bootstrap/boo
>   tstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>
> INFO     2014-07-19 08:59:39,178 module.py:627] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/
>   1.1" 200 1354

It looks like there is "TypeError". How to fix this error? How to load CSS file?

Comment: You need to check the logs to find the cause of the 500 error

Comment: @GAEfan thanks, I add server log to my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a bug in the app.yaml static handlers for Windows:

[Google App Engine: Won't serve static assets with below error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106776/google-app-engine-wont-serve-static-assets-with-below-error/24107830#24107830)